# Strange behavior when trying to plot single values

Tags: gnuplot

I am using the following Gnuplot script :

```
#####  Definitions  ####
a=0.3
s0=10.
s1=-9.999
r1u(x)=-exp(x)*(-1+a+a*exp(x))/((1+exp(x))**3)
r2u(x)=exp(x)*(1-exp(x))*(-1+a+a*exp(x))/((1+exp(x))**4)
f1(c,d)=s0*c*(1-2*a)/2. + s1*r1u(d)
f2(c,d)=1./(3.*c) - s0*c/6. + s1*r2u(d)
dummyx(z)=25.
dummyy1(z)=.08
dummyy2(z)=.06

#####   Prologue   #####
clear
reset

######  Plot data   #####
set zeroaxis
set key title 'plot of dw/dt'
plot '019999.rrp' using 1:(f2(($4),($5))) with linespoints linewidth 2 notitle
pause -1
stats '019999.rrp' using 5 nooutput
do for [i=0:int(STATS_records-1)] {
    reset
    set term x11 1
    set key title '-x0/w at t'.i.' and its position on the "source term" curve'
    set xrange [STATS_min:STATS_max]
    set label 1 sprintf("t = %3.0f",i) at 25,.04
    set label 2 'w is' at 19,.08
    set label 3 'dw/dt is' at 19,.06
    plot '019999.rrp' every ::i::i:1 using 5:(r1u($5)) linewidth 5 notitle,\
         '019999.rrp' every ::i::i:1 using (dummyx($1)):(dummyy1($1)):4 with labels notitle,\
         '019999.rrp' every ::i::i:1 using (dummyx($1)):(dummyy2($1)):(f2(($4),($5))) with labels notitle,\
         r1u(x) with lines lw 2 notitle
    pause -1
}
```

and the last `f2(($4),($5))` doesn't do what it should. It just plots `($5)`. However the first `f2(($4),($5))` works.

The plotted file is here : http://we.tl/SPX4ykaX4j . I don't know if it's good practice to provide a link, so here is the head of this file which is sufficient to reproduce the error.

```
0.0000000E+00  -15.00000      -60.00000      0.4472136       33.54102    
0.2500000      -14.77640      0.8944144      0.4472048       33.04168    
0.5000000      -14.55279      0.8944079      0.4472023       32.54186    
0.7500000      -14.32919      0.8944058      0.4472016       32.04191    
1.000000      -14.10559      0.8944051      0.4472014       31.54192    
1.250000      -13.88199      0.8944049      0.4472013       31.04193
1.500000      -13.65839      0.8944048      0.4472013       30.54193    
1.750000      -13.43479      0.8944047      0.4472013       30.04193    
2.000000      -13.21119      0.8944047      0.4472013       29.54193    
2.250000      -12.98759      0.8944047      0.4472013       29.04193    
2.500000      -12.76398      0.8944047      0.4472013       28.54192    
2.750000      -12.54038      0.8944046      0.4472012       28.04193    
3.000000      -12.31678      0.8944047      0.4472013       27.54192    
3.250000      -12.09318      0.8944047      0.4472013       27.04192    
3.500000      -11.86958      0.8944047      0.4472013       26.54192    
3.750000      -11.64598      0.8944047      0.4472013       26.04192    
4.000000      -11.42238      0.8944047      0.4472013       25.54192    
4.250000      -11.19878      0.8944047      0.4472013       25.04192    
4.500000      -10.97517      0.8944047      0.4472013       24.54191    
4.750000      -10.75157      0.8944047      0.4472013       24.04191    
5.000000      -10.52797      0.8944047      0.4472013       23.54191    
5.250000      -10.30437      0.8944046      0.4472012       23.04191    
5.500000      -10.08077      0.8944047      0.4472013       22.54191    
5.750000      -9.857169      0.8944047      0.4472013       22.04191    
6.000000      -9.633568      0.8944047      0.4472013       21.54191    
6.250000      -9.409966      0.8944047      0.4472013       21.04191    
6.500000      -9.186366      0.8944047      0.4472013       20.54190    
6.750000      -8.962765      0.8944047      0.4472013       20.04190    
7.000000      -8.739163      0.8944047      0.4472013       19.54190    
7.250000      -8.515562      0.8944047      0.4472013       19.04190    
7.500000      -8.291961      0.8944047      0.4472013       18.54190    
7.750000      -8.068360      0.8944046      0.4472012       18.04190    
8.000000      -7.844759      0.8944047      0.4472013       17.54190    
8.250000      -7.621158      0.8944047      0.4472013       17.04190    
8.500000      -7.397556      0.8944047      0.4472013       16.54189    
8.750000      -7.173955      0.8944047      0.4472013       16.04189    
9.000000      -6.950354      0.8944047      0.4472013       15.54189    
9.250000      -6.726753      0.8944047      0.4472013       15.04189    
9.500000      -6.503151      0.8944047      0.4472013       14.54189
```

Comment: I'm using Version 4.6 patchlevel 5.

Comment: To people who upvoted : were you able to reproduce the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is fixed, if you use `sprintf` to format the function value:

```
...
plot '019999.rrp' every ::i::i using (dummyx($1)):(dummyy2($1)):(sprintf("%g", f2(($4),($5)))) with labels notitle
...
```

The same error (?) can be reproduced with the following, simplified example:

```
set samples 11
set xrange [0:10]
f(x,y) = x+y
unset key

set multiplot layout 2,1
plot '+' using 1:1:(f($1,$1)) with labels
plot '+' using 1:1:(sprintf("%g", f($1,$1))) with labels
unset multiplot
```

I don't know, if that may be regarded as a bug. I reported it as [#1368 Conversion of numerical expressions in string columns](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1368/) .

[image]

Comment: Dear Christoph, it works now like a charm ! Thanks for the bug (?) report. I read it carefully and found it is related to non-trivial questions (to me)...    But maybe I am doing too sophisticated things ? If you read my script, you see that I just want to print on my graph the value of some variables (or their values against a given function). Is there another way to do that ?

Comment: The basic message of the discussion in the report is, that the third column must contain a string, which you can create with a `sprintf` statement like shown in the answer. The rest is about how automatic conversion of numerical expressions or values to string could be achieved, an if an error message should be generated if no conversion is possible, like in your case.