# Gnuplot label not processed by function

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following `rule_times.dat` file:

```
0 min 4246
0.5 min 26543
1.5 max 38339128
2 max 7293253
3 avg 103698.380554429
3.5 avg 43305.9820981295
```

and the following `gnuplot` script:

```
reset
set style line 1 lc rgb "#c42f27"
set style line 2 lc rgb "#2f27c4"
set terminal png
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid

set xtics("min" 0.25, "max" 1.75, "avg" 3.25)

set ylabel "log(time for 1000 evaluations)"
set ytics 10000
set yrange [0:25]

to_us(x)=floor(x/1000)
set title "Evaluation times for direct rule evaluation"

plot "rule_times.dat" using 1:(log($3)):(to_us($3)) with labels offset character 0, character 1 tc rgb "black" title "", \
    "rule_times.dat" every 2 using 1:(log($3)) with boxes ls 1 title "log(eval)", \
    "rule_times.dat" every 2::1 using 1:(log($3)) with boxes ls 2 title "log(lookup)"
```

and am obtaining the following output:
[image: plot]

I want the numbers to be divided by 1000 and rounded/floored/whatever so that the labels on top of the bars are smaller numbers, but the function seems to not be applied! What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `floor(x/1000)` returns a number which must be converted to a string. Some ideas:

Implicit conversion by appending the result to an empty string:

```
to_us(x)="".floor(x/1000)
```

Explicit conversion with probably more flexibility:

```
to_us(x)=sprintf("%6.2f", (x/1000))
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/22832519/2604213 and the linked discussion on sourceforge.

Comment: Does it make a difference whether `x/1000` or x/1000.0` is being used? I had situations where an integer division was done...